# Visual Studio deletes my CMake.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, cmake

I'm installing OpenCV from this [very out of date] [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

I made it through the configuration step and everything seemed fine, but then when I try to build the OpenCV.sln, I get a bunch of these errors:

```
Checking Build System
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

... (etc)

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 63 failed, 0 up-to-date, 6 skipped ==========
```

It's trying to find the cmake.exe file, whereas that directory only contains cmake-gui.exe (It seems cmake-gui.exe is the only thing that ships with Cmake 3.0.1 for Windows).

**What should I do?** Install an old version of cmake? Rename the executable? Or is there some way to point Visual Studio to use cmake-gui.exe instead?

P.S. I'm on Windows 7, using Visual Studio 2010 Pro

*Edit*

Woah. Ok with David's help I downloaded and installed cmake.exe in the right place. Now when I go to build the ZERO_CHECK project I get this:

```
CustomBuild:
Checking Build System
Access is denied.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 5.

Build FAILED.
```

And (here's the kicker), the cmake.exe file has been **deleted**. It's gone. What the heck? I'm running Visual Studio as Administrator, why would access be denied?

Comment: It sounds like you have a build error, cmake should have generated a log file, check that.

Comment: Ah, you're right @Ramhound. It's looking for 'unistd.h'. I'll search around and solve that problem now. Do you have any idea why cmake would have been deleted afterwards, though? That still seems weird to me.

Comment: I don't even know what your trying to build.  If you are trying to build say cmake itself that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sure, that would make sense. But I'm building OpenCV. (See first line of OP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `cmake.exe` is missing

The zip file `cmake-3.0.1-win32-x86.zip` from http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html contains the following files in the `bin` subdirectory:

```
9,035,264 cmake-gui.exe
3,283,456 cmake.exe                         <------
  156,160 cmcldeps.exe
3,218,944 cpack.exe
3,696,640 ctest.exe
1,177,088 libeay32.dll
      524 Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
  224,768 msvcm90.dll
  568,832 msvcp90.dll
  655,872 msvcr90.dll
  270,336 ssleay32.dll
```

Comment: Ok, that helped, thanks! But now I've got a new problem (or more likely just clarified the original problem). I've edited my OP.